# How to get RPM's that has been published after the install DVD?

Tags: yum, rpm, scientific-linux

So if I download a:

```
SL-63-x86_64-2012-08-02-Install-DVD.iso
```

and install it, and give out a "yum update" - then it will find many-many XY packages to update.

**Q:** are there any methods/solutions to get these XY rpm's? (and then I can put them in the: "/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6.3/" - because internet connection is not too fast.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a perfect use for yum-downloadonly.

1. Run `yum install yum-downloadonly`
2. `yum update --downloadonly --downloaddir=/path/to/dir`

NixCraft has an excellent [write-up](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-downloadonly-plugin/) on this tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can download them from the main site http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.3/x86_64/updates/ or a mirror (see https://www.scientificlinux.org/download)

Answer (score 0):

You should build your own local mirror for the update-repositories.

According to the SL-download-page there is a rsync-mirror:
[rsync://rsync.scientificlinux.org/scientific/](https://www.scientificlinux.org/download) Use this in times where no one is using your slow internet-connection to build up the mirror and keep it current daily.

You can then export that local mirror via http and include that one instead of the internet-update-repository.