# Cant install gnutls.i686 on a x64 CentOS install

Tags: centos, yum

I need to install `gnutls.i686` on CentOS 7 but I get this error in yum:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/man/man5/pkcs11.conf.5.gz from install of p11-kit-0.18.7-4.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package p11-kit-0.18.7-4.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man8/p11-kit.8.gz from install of p11-kit-0.18.7-4.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package p11-kit-0.18.7-4.el7.x86_64
```

I dont know if this is a bug I should report to the CentOS team of if it's just another regular conflict.

The only way I can think of fixing this is either deleting those files or having yum override the conflict and install it anyway.

Full output of yum: http://pastebin.com/ZHWbHrHJ

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is due to same files of the man pages in both i686 and x64 'p11-kit' packages. You need to workaround this problem with help of option `rpm -ivh --excludedocs`.

You first need to install the package which has conflict by using `--excludedocs` option, first download the required package `p11-kit-0.18.7-4.el7.i686.rpm` and then install it with following option:

```
rpm -ivh --excludedocs p11-kit-0.18.7-4.el7.i686.rpm
```

And after this run your command `yum install gnutls.i686`.

More efforts are required to find the package, or you can use [yum offline updating](http://wiki.contribs.org/Yum_offline_updating) to copy that package, or use [yum downloadonly plugin.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49676/how-to-get-rpms-that-has-been-published-after-the-install-dvd)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with multilib installs. This has been fixed in the 6/17 or later trees.

BTW..  This code is very much alpha right now and should only be used for testing purposes until the real release.