# System upgrade conflicts

Tags: fedora, software-installation, upgrade

I'm getting a lot of conflicts when upgrading system. I can't remove these packages because many important packages depend on it. I really am not sure what to do now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messages show that you have a conflict between a 32-bit package and a 64-bit package.  That could have happened as a result of mixing repositories from different places (there's not enough information in the question to clarify this).

However, you may be able to remove the *32-bit* package without disturbing anything that you actually need.  Rather than

```
yum remove gnutls
```

if you did

```
yum remove gnutls.i686
```

you would see a smaller list, perhaps small enough to decide to remove those programs — temporarily perhaps — and then do the upgrade.  If the removed packages included something that you needed, you could add it back at that point.

Further reading:

- [Conflicts between new 32 bit and old 64 bit packages when installing rpmfusion's steam on fedora](https://superuser.com/questions/994151/conflicts-between-new-32-bit-and-old-64-bit-packages-when-installing-rpmfusions)
- [Bug 1246712: dnf upgrade gnutls fails because of packaging issues](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1246712)
- [Cant install gnutls.i686 on a x64 CentOS install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137726/cant-install-gnutls-i686-on-a-x64-centos-install)